# system-resolvd starts using local nameserver as DNS whenever network is not available

Tags: debian, systemd, dns, raspbian, systemd-resolved

I have an IoT device that is connected to a node via a local wireless network. After doing the computations, the device tries to posts the data to the cloud. The device is connected to the internet via a 4g cellular network.

Everything works as expected if the internet connection is present. But in the case of a device being offline, system-resolved starts using the IP address of the local node as DNS and keeps on retrying to post the data rather than raising an exception. It remains stuck on the post-call for around two to three minutes before raising an exception. The device is running raspbian OS.

How to deny system-resolvd from taking the locally cached nameserver as DNS?

Comment: Have you given this nameserver as an option to be considered? If so, it will be considered and used. If you don't want it used then don't offer it as an option

Comment: @roaima How to check if it's set as an option to be considered?